# solving Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For equation below:

$$(t+1) \, dx=4(x+4) \, dt$$

After separation  I ended up with:

$$(x+4)dx = \frac 4{t+1}dt $$

Resulting in:

$$\int x+4 \,dx = 4 \int \frac 1{t+1} \,dt$$

So:

$$\frac 12 x^2  + 4x + C = 4\ln(t+1) + C$$

Now I have to express this as $x(t)$ and I have no clue how to. Also I am not sure if I did the above steps correctly. Any help will be appriciated!

**UPDATE**

As gerry pointed my mistake now I have:

$$ \int \frac {1}{x+4}\,dx = 4\int \frac{1}{t+1}\,dt  $$

Then:

$$ \ln(x+4) = 4 \ln(t+1) + C$$

Still not able to express this as x(t)...how to?!

Comment: First step is wrong - should be $dx/(x+4)$ on the left.

Comment: After you do the separation of variables correctly and integrate, one "$C$" is enough. If you really really want to (but you shouldn't), a $C$ and a $D$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks I had a mistake, I updated my question. please have a look

Comment: Take the exponential of both sides.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No idea how to deal with that +4 on left and +1 on right :(

Comment: $\exp(\log(Q))=Q$, no matter what $Q$ is.

Comment: And $a\ln Q=\ln (Q^a)$.

Comment: I have to have only $x(t)$ on left side. That 4 on left and 1 on right really confuses me.

Comment: $e^{\ln(x+1)}=x+1$. And $e^{4\ln(t+4)}=(t+4)^4$. Get $x+1=e^C(t+4)^4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you've done all the calculus.  The rest is just algebra.  Taking the exponential of both sides, we get:

$x+4=e^{4\ln(t+1)+C}=e^Ce^{\ln(t+1)^4}=k(t+1)^4$

$x=k(t+1)^4-4$